# LIKE or CHARINDEX to check String Contains a Substring

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

To check a string contains a sub string or not we can use `[LIKE]` or  `[CHARINDEX]`.
I know that like uses indexing in case we have name%.(while %name% may not use index) .Also charindex does not use index.
 For example I want to get all rows containing employeename as 'av'

```
select * from employee where CHARINDEX('av', employeename)>0
```

OR i can do same by using LIKE

```
select * from employee where employeename LIKE '%av%'
```

In this case which one is better to use? Charindex or like? Why?

Comment: Neither are sargable. I'd start by comparing the query plans, but I imagine you'll get a full index scan for both.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson Yes. both are not sargable. So which one would perform better in general?

Comment: My test suggests that the LIKE is "slightly" faster.  Note that LIKE looks for existence, but CHARINDEX also reports on the string's position.